# flame Field 'body' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, flame

I met an error after flame updated to 1.4, here is the code:

```
class Ball extends BodyComponent {
   ...
     Vector2 get position =>
      //camera.worldToScreen(body?.position ?? Vector2.zero());
        body?.position ?? Vector2.zero(); // <-error: flame Field 'body' has not been initialized
   ...

}
```

I noticed that from 1.0 to 1.4 Body added a late in the package and could be initialized through createBody(), but why `body?.position ?? Vector2.zero()` does not work as i know the real-time position of the ball? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a field has the `late` keyword it does not mean that the value can be null, which is what you are checking with the `?.` and `??`, `late` means that you promise the runtime that the field will be initialized before it is used.

`createBody` initializes the `body` and only after that has run the `BodyComponent` can be properly used. `createBody` runs automatically in `onLoad`, which is why it is important to call `super.onLoad` the first thing you do if you override `onLoad`.

Comment: hi spydon thank you again for your support. true, now it works after I move super.onload to the top, before it is on the last line of onload method as return super.onLoad();  What I tried is to put body?.position ?? Vector2.zero() in the onMout, but yours is right solution, thank you!